# A Quadratic Maximum?

Tags: real-analysis, definition, harmonic-analysis

What does the following mean?

Context: Laplace integrals

> Consider the integral $$\int_a^b f(t) \exp(x\phi(t))\,\,\,dt$$ where $\phi(t) $ achieves its maximum at some $t=c\in (a,b)$. ***Assume that the maximum is quadratic.***

What could a "quadratic maximum" mean?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know, but maybe if you add what you need to prove / what is proven under this assumption we can infer from context?

Comment: It proceeds to say that then the integral behaves like a Gaussian integral near $c$. I suppose it means that $\phi(t)$ can be approximated by a function of the form $ax^2+bx+c$? Or simply $ax^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\phi(t)$ reaches a maximum at $c$, assuming that $\phi''(c)\lt0$, near $c$ we have
$$
\begin{align}
\phi(t)
&=\phi(c)+\phi'(c)(t-c)+\frac12\phi''(t-c)(t-c)^2+O(t-c)^3\\
&=\phi(c)+\frac12\phi''(t-c)(t-c)^2+O(t-c)^3
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $\phi$ behaves like a quadratic function near $c$.

Therefore, we get the [stationary phase approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_phase_approximation):
$$
\begin{align}
\int_a^bf(t)e^{x\phi(t)}\,\mathrm{d}t
&\stackrel.=e^{x\phi(c)}\int_a^bf(t)e^{\frac12x\phi''(c)(t-c)^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&\stackrel.=e^{x\phi(c)}f(c)\sqrt{\frac{\vphantom{\lambda}2\pi}{-x\phi''(c)}}
\end{align}
$$